# Sending POST Request through JSON API Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http, post

I'm using oAuth2 and I'm trying to figure out the best way to POST login credentials to the API and receive the secret, secret_id, and token in return.

The JSON formatting for the log_in portion of the API looks like:

```
POST auth/log_in HTTP/1.1
Host: hostSite.com
Content-Type: application/JSON
Authorization: Basic Base64(client_id:client_secret)
{
    "username": "email@example.com"
    "password": "Purpl3H0rs3Oc3an"
    "grant_type": "password"
    "request_refresh": "true"
}
```

What I have for the sending the login credentials is:

```
 - (BOOL) loginUser
{
NSString *  sUserName = [m_jsonDict valueForKey:@"username"],
         *  sPassword = [m_jsonDict valueForKey:@"password"],
         *  sJSON = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"userName: %@\npassword: %@\n",
                                              sUserName, sPassword];

return ([self POSTUsingCommand:@"login" andData:sJSON]);
}
```

Then to actually send the request:

```
     (BOOL) POSTUsingCommand : (NSString *) sCommand
         andData                : (NSString *) sData
{
    BOOL                    ret = NO;
    NSString            *   url = [NSString stringWithFormat:CONST_PATH, NSLocalizedString(sCommand, nil)]; 
    //hostSite.com/auth/log_in

    NSString            *   sHTTPBody = sData;
    NSMutableURLRequest *   request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                          timeoutInterval:15.0];

#if defined(DEBUG)
    NSLog(@"--- POSTUsingCommand:\n%@\n", sHTTPBody);
#endif

    // build out the post command

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"Application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"Application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sHTTPBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if ([NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                      delegate:self] == nil)
    {
#if defined(DEBUG)
        NSLog(@"There was a problem with initWithRequest:delegate\n");
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        ret = YES;
    }

    return (ret);
}
```

Now when testing my code I inspect the `response` variable in the `connection:DidReceiveResponse` method. The status of the request is a 400. Why do I get this error is there additional setup that needs to be done?

Comment: I'd give some serious thought to using [AFOAuth2Manager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager) which takes all of this headache out of the equation ;)

Comment: What's the NSLog for the `sHTTPBody` ?

Comment: Thanks @remus I looked into AFOAuth2Manager. However I, ideally, want to try and accomplish this without any third party frameworks.

Comment: @ntsh username: email@example.com password: Purpl3H0rs3Oc3an (these values are assigned from a username and password textfield in a login view controller).

Comment: So, here's your answer. This data is not in json format which your server is expecting.

Comment: I suppose that's a problem then, how would I format the data in the `-(BOOL) loginUser` so that it is in JSON Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sHTTPBody` is not in json format. To get this as json, you can create a dictionary of your data. Then convert it into json using json serialization.

**Prepare Dictionary from your data:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dataDict setObject:sUserName forKey:@"username"];
[dataDict setObject:sPassword forKey:@"password"];
// And so on ...
```

**Convert dictionary into Json data:**

```
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict 
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
```

**Finally send a post request with json data:**

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

This should work. Take care of the syntax and minor errors in this code. I have not tested it. You might have to tweak your methods a bit to use this code.